# Determine whether these quotient group of multiplicative group under modulo $16$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group of modulo $16$; that is, $G=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$. Next, let $H=\{1,15\}$ and $K=\{1,9\}$. Determine whether $G/H$ and $G/K$ are isomorphic.

**Attempt:**
Define a mapping $f:G/H \to G/K$ by $f(gH)=gK$ for all $g \in G$.
This mapping is indeed a group homomorphism:
Let $g_1H,g_2H \in gH$. Notice that
$$f((g_1H)(g_2H)) = f(g_1g_2H) = g_1g_2K = (g_1K)(g_2K) = f(g_1H)f(g_2H).$$
But, I have a little bit trouble when showing injectivity. For any $g_1H,g_2H \in gH$ such that $f(g_1H)=f(g_2H)$, how to show that $g_1H=g_2H$?

Any ideas? Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Before proving that $f$ is an homomorphism you need to prove first that $f$ is a mapping, that is, you need to prove it's well defined.

Comment: @jjagmath OK, and then? What about my question (injectivity)?

Comment: I'm afraid that you missed the point of my first comment. Your mapping is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, your way doesn't work.

Alternatively, notice that $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic group of order $4$ generated by $3H$, while $\frac{G}{K}$ is a non cyclic group of order $4$, as every element of $\frac{G}{K}$ had order $2$. Hence they are not isomorphic.